# Alternative to multiple regexes for replacing known words in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, substitution

In Python 3 I have the string " up2 left5 right4 down2". I wish to convert this to " u2 l5 r4 d2", keeping the numbers. What's the most efficient way of doing this? I imagine there's a better method than 4 regexes.

The only possible words are "up" "down" "left" and "right", the numbers can be anything from 0 to 999. How can I efficiently replace these 4 words with their 1-character abbreviations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for t in (('up', 'u'), ('down','d'), ('left','l'), ('right', 'r')):
   mystring = mystring.replace(*t)
```

or, taking advantage of the fact that replacement for a word is always its first letter:

```
for word in ('up','down','left','right'):
    mystring = mystring.replace(word, word[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Błotosmętek's solution(which is going to be slightly slower), you can have a dictionary containing the words as keys and their first letter as a value:

```
d = {"up": "u", "down": "d", "left": "l", "right": "r"}

for key, val in d.items():
    s = s.replace(key, val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = "up2 left5 right4 down2"
[ l[0][0] + l[1] for l in re.findall(r'([a-z]*)(\d+)', s ) ]
```

Output :

```
['u2', 'l5', 'r4', 'd2']
```